# Best Practices for Validate field in Salesforce

Tags: trigger, community, bestpractice, validation-rule

This is my scenario:

```
 - Object Name: Contact . 
 - Field:
    -Status__c (Picklist) contains: Active ,Inactive or NULL
    -StatusDetail__c (Text)
```

The requirement is whenever Status not null , we don't want user to update StatusDetail if the StatusDetail previously is not null. Meaning if currently StatusDetail contains value, it won't be updated if Status is not null. This validation should apply in UI and also update through backend such as Apex class or DataLoader.

Initially I created Validation Rule on StatusDetail__c such as:

```
AND(NOT(ISBLANK( TEXT(Status__c )) ) ,NOT(ISBLANK( PRIORVALUE(StatusDetail__c ))),ISCHANGED(StatusDetail__c ))
```

But I have problem when I try to edit Status field through UI, not StatusDetail, it won't allow to Save at all. While it should allow me to save because I only update Status not StatusDetail.
Then I read [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_validation_considerations.htm&language=en_US) that Validation rule won't apply on certain case as below:

> Validation rules continue to run on individual records if the owner is
>   changed. If the Mass Transfer tool is used to change the ownership of
>   multiple records, however, validation rules won’t run on those
>   records.

Now I am thinking maybe doing in trigger is the best way, but is there any other method that I need to try first before proceeding with trigger? Or is TRIGGER actually the best for my situation?

Comment: Does `Status__c` have a default value of `Inactive` or can it also be left `Blank`? It appears to me that may be at the root of your problem. A picklist can have data entered into it other than what's in the list. If the default is `None`, that may not necessarily be `Blank` if you entered a space, carriage return or other character in the 3rd placeholder of the list or other data somehow got entered into into your database.

Comment: @crmprogdev , yes the picklist also can be NULL .We don't want user to update StatusDetail__c if Status__c is not null/blank and previous value of StatusDetail__c not blank.

Comment: If that's the case, you may want to test for the other two conditions instead, meaning `TEXT(Status__c) = "Active" OR "Inactive"` rather than testing against the `NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Status__c)) )` condition used at the beginning of your rule. The two are equivalent but allow for what can happen with data populated in picklists. I agree with @UweHeim, no need for a trigger here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I m trying to figure out this statement :'Validation rules continue to run on individual records if the owner is changed. If the Mass Transfer tool is used to change the ownership of multiple records, however, validation rules won’t run on those records. ' What is it mean?Is it will not apply on back end update?

Comment: That's correct. If there's a mass transfer of records to a new owner, the validation rules will not be run. Unless you have a validation rule that depends on who the Owner is, there really should be no need to be concerned about this. Note that this is distinct from a workflow rule used for something like case assignment or lead assignment where other criteria would come into play when assigning ownership. That's workflow, not validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion your approach is fine and I see no pressing need for a trigger here. If it can be done with validation, I would suggest to avoid the trigger as long as possible.

I implemented the scenario you have described in a DE org and wasn't able to see that it does not work, i.e. I'm able to change Status__c whether or not StatusDetail__c is NULL and I can change StatusDetail__c as long Status__c is NULL. Hope, that I got your requirements right so far.

If you think you have some reproducible clicking sequence which does not do what you want, please let me no and I will have a look on it.

I hope that no other settings or other validation rules may interfere on your org.

Comment: Based on your answer, I will take it as better use validation rule.Using trigger only when there no option for Validation rule.